# Named pipe stdout redirection instead of numeric file descriptor

Tags: shell, pipe, fifo, node.js

So I was fiddling around for hours now. I have the following problem:

I am running a command (node.js script) that writes to `stdout` via `process.stdout.write`. It is interactive and at one point it will exit.

I need the exit result so I created a subshell but I also need it to be active on the parent so I redirect the output to the parent shell like this:

```bsh
exec 4>&1; res=$(exec 3>&1 1>&4; node test.js)
```

**What is the idea behind that command?**
`1>&4` makes sure that the output of node test.js is going to the main (parent) shell. With `3>&1` I am opening another pipe to be able to write the RESULT of the process to the subshell so that I can have it in `$res`.

Example (pseudocode):

```
//node.js script:
process.stdout.write('write to parent shell because 1>&4')
writeToPipe('/dev/fd/3', 'write the RESULT to subshell so that we can have it in the $res variable')
```

**Now what is the issue with that?**

The issue is (maybe due to misunderstandings on my side shell/unix-wise) that I do not want to simply write to `/dev/fd/3` because what if someone else is writing to `/dev/fd/3` as well? I would think that this is not a very good implementation to just simply open the `fd/3` and use that. What if someone calls multiple of my processes and they collide?

**How I tried to solve it**

I thought i could do something like:

```
tmppipe=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$tmppipe"
```

Because I could generate a unique named pipe every time and avoid collisions.

The problem is that I do not get it working. In a way of "trivial substitution" I was trying this at first:

```bsh
exec 4>&1; res=$(exec "$tmppipe">&1 1>&4; node test.js)
```

But this does not work. I assume it does not work with this syntax for named pipes but what I get is that the terminal tells me that there is a permission problem and it quits.

Comment: File descriptors are local to a process, or there would be issues with file descriptors 1 and 2.

Comment: So that means in my node process I can rely on writing to `/dev/fd/3` since my node process gets access to that very one ? How would I then know if the file descriptors are REALLY at `/dev/fd/3` ? Is it different depending on the OS?

Comment: It looks like this is guaranteed by the shell script.

Comment: Reading your text, I can't see why you don't just use `res=$(node test.js)`

Comment: Because that locks stdout etc. in the subshell and therefore hides it away. The `test.js` however is interactive.

Comment: What does "locks stdout away" mean? If `test.js` needs to prompt the user (or do other forms of output related to interacting with the user), it should use standard error for this. This is an accepted way to interact with the user  and how the shell does it as well (prompts, for example, are written to the shell's stderr stream).

Comment: So I shall pipe to `&2` instead? Wouldn't this be the same thing then but just shorter? `res=$(exec 3>&1 1>&2; node test.js)`

Or can you give me sample of what you mean?

Comment: I mean that the `test.js` code should write to the user on standard error. The user replies on standard input. Final output from `test.js` is produced on standard output and is assigned to the shell variable `res`.

Comment: I see so basically `$(echo "test" >/dev/fd/2)` super-simplified. But why does the stderr output on the parent? Is `stderr` always accumulated on the parent process?

Comment: A better example would have been (in `bash`) `res=$(read -p 'input please: '; echo "I got $REPLY"); echo "$res"`  Here, `read` asks the user for input on standard error, reads from standard input, and then `echo` produces some output on standard output which is captured in `res`. I don't know what you mean by "accumulated on the parent process"...

Comment: When I meant "accumulation" I was talking about wondering why the subshell echoes `stderr` in the parent. So I assumed the same as with `/dev/fd/1` (so subshell has its own  output which is the reason why its output is locked in the subshell normally. So I assumed that if I write to `stderr` it would be locked in the subshells error output

Comment: No, the command substitution only captures the output stream, not the error stream.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll summarize in an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you're intending with your pipe and with the file descriptor juggling that you do is for the `test.js` to have some form of interactive dialog with the user.

You use standard output in `test.js` to e.g. ask questions to the user, and the user replies on standard input. Since the `test.js` program needs to provide its final output on standard output somehow, for the data to be supplied to the command substitution, you organize for file descriptor 3 to be connected to standard output in the substitution and write the final output to this descriptor in `test.js`.

This is a bit awkward.

The commonly accepted way of handling interactive user dialogues that isn't part of a tool's final output, i.e. interactive questions, diagnostic error messages, progress bars etc., is to output these on the standard error stream.  This will, by default, cause these messages to go directly to the terminal (assuming no redirection of file descriptor 2 has been set up), and they would therefore not be the result captured by a command substitution or a sent over a pipe etc.

This is how the shell and many other tools work.  The shell prompts on standard error.  The `bash` shell writes its `select` statement output (a sort of menu) on standard error, the `read -p 'text'` command prints `text` on the standard error stream to prompt the user, and (obviously) it outputs error messages on standard error.

So, you code could be simplified as

```
res=$(node test.js)
```

where `test.js` would interact with the user on the standard error stream, read the user's input on the standard input stream and finally produce some output on the standard output stream that should be stored in the variable `res` in the shell.

A short demo of this, in the `bash` shell:

```
res=$( read -p 'enter something: '; printf 'You entered "%s"\n' "$REPLY" )
printf '"$res" is now "%s"\n' "$res"
```

The final value in `res` will *not* contain the string `enter something:`  since that was written to the standard error stream by the `read` utility.